# Why CSS contains() fail to work with Protractor?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In Protractor, the xpath `contains[.,'']` works all time instead of CSS's `contains()` feature; is there any cause for such broken functionality? or any tweak to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pseudo class `contains` is not a CSS feature. It's implemented by external libraries like JQuery or Mootools. To get an element by text, use the locator `by.cssContainingText`:

```
var elem = element(by.cssContainingText('div.left', 'my text'));
```